# FragmentActivity onActivityResult data is null

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I know there are several questions about this, but I don't found a solution for my problem.

I have `ActivityA` which extends `AppCompatActivity`. It starts an `ActivityB`

**Activity A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("data", data);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

....

@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int result, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, intent);
    if (requestCode != 1) { // check code
        return;
    }

    if (intent == null) { // HERE INTENT IS NULL 

       return;
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
// code called when an asynctask is done
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("dataone", "test");
i.putExtra("datatwo", objet);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

I don't understand why `intent` is `null` in `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: perhaps you missed this line in the OnActivityResult() `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, result, intent);`

Comment: nop :( I wrote it.

Comment: Kindly post, the essential code of the onActivityResult method and also Activity B class.

Comment: Done :) Thx for ur help

Comment: what about the Activity B class? kindly post its essential code as well

Comment: yeah you should post the part of the code where you call setResult in activity B. for ex. onBackPressed, onDestroy, etc.?

Comment: Nop, I called this code in my Activity B, when an asynctask is done.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. I would refactor your code like the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      // example
      // String myString = intent.getString("myStringFrom2ndActivity")

        }
    }
}
```

and also make sure that you are calling the right RESULT_OK. It should be something like Activity.RESULT_OK.

Comment: Nop, it doesn't work, it's the same thing what I did.